# Add custom text + variable to a varchar in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

i'm trying to make a txt file with a single command line output in it.
However for some reason it doesn't want to add the text and the test name into it..
Here's my code:

```
    declare @command AS varchar(200)
declare @cmd AS varchar(200)
declare @input AS varchar(200)
declare @timeinput AS varchar(200)
declare @test AS varchar(1000)
declare @failureid as int

select @timeinput = (select time from inserted)
select @input = (select action from inserted)
select @failureid = (select failureId from inserted)

select @test = (select name from dbo.Alert where FailureId = @failureid)


if (@input = 'start')
BEGIN
set @command = ('EnableTest' + @test)
END

if (@input = 'stop')
BEGIN
set @command = ('DisableTest' + @test)
END

if (@input = 'pauze')
set @command = ('PauseTest' + @test + @timeinput)
END

SET @cmd = 'echo ' + @command + ' > F:\commandfolder\testing.HMS'
EXECUTE Master.dbo.xp_CmdShell @cmd
```

and the output in the HMS file is: DisableTest (with the testname missing)
The @test doesn't add into the file.

The data in my tables is correct as far as I know
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance & kind regards,

Dave

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
 declare @command AS varchar(200)
 declare @cmd AS varchar(200)
 declare @input AS varchar(200)
 declare @timeinput AS varchar(200)
 declare @test AS varchar(1000)
 declare @failureid as int
 select @timeinput = (select time from inserted) 
 select @input = (select action from inserted)
 select @failureid = (select failureId from inserted)
 select @test = (select name from dbo.Alert where FailureId = @failureid)
 if (@input = 'start')
 BEGIN
 set @failureid = (select failureId from inserted where action= @input)
 set @test = (select name from dbo.Alert where FailureId = @failureid)
 set @command = ('EnableTest' + @test)
 END

 if (@input = 'stop')
 BEGIN
 set @failureid = (select failureId from inserted where action= @input)
 set @test = (select name from dbo.Alert where FailureId = @failureid)
 set @command = ('DisableTest' + @test)
 END

 if (@input = 'pauze')
 begin
 set @failureid = (select failureId from inserted where action= @input)
 set @test = (select name from dbo.Alert where FailureId = @failureid)
 set @command = ('PauseTest' + @test + @timeinput)
 END

 SET @cmd = 'echo ' + @command + ' > F:\commandfolder\testing.HMS'
 EXECUTE Master.dbo.xp_CmdShell @cmd
```

Basicaly, my guess is that you will have to set the Variable for every single case otherswise it remains the same.

Comment: I'll that a go and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be working now with no adjustments. 
I don't know why it didn't, but the code is correct.